# Array variable access problem in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a problem that I can't figure out even after a couple of hours of testing different ways to achieve what I need: Here is the code I have a problem with:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

#import "NewsRssParser.h"
#import "NewsRss.h"

@class NewsRssParser;
@class NewsRss;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,NewsRssParserDelegate> {
 NewsRssParser * _rssParser; 
 NSMutableArray * _newsRssArray;
}

@property(readwrite, retain) NewsRssParser * rssParser;
@property(readwrite, retain) NSMutableArray * newsRssArray;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize rssParser = _rssParser;
@synthesize newsRssArray = _newsRssArray;

[...]

- (void)myFunction{

 NSMutableArray *dsItems = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

 for(NSMutableArray *rssItem in self.rssParser.rssItems)
 {
  NSString * rssItemTitle = [(NewsRss *)rssItem title];
  NSString * rssItemAuthor = [@"par " stringByAppendingString:[(NewsRss *)rssItem author]];
  NSString * rssItemDescription = [(NewsRss *)rssItem description];
  NSString * rssItemLinkUrl = [(NewsRss *)rssItem linkUrl];
  NSString * rssItemImageUrl = [(NewsRss *)rssItem mediaUrl];

  TTTableMessageItem *tMsgItem = [TTTableMessageItem itemWithTitle:rssItemTitle caption:rssItemAuthor text:rssItemDescription timestamp:nil imageURL:rssItemImageUrl URL:rssItemLinkUrl];
  [self.newsRssArray addObject:tMsgItem];
  [dsItems addObject:tMsgItem];
 }

 NSLog(@"AppDelegate/count/rssItems=%d", [self.rssParser.rssItems count]);
 NSLog(@"AppDelegate/count/newsRssArray=%d", [self.newsRssArray count]);
 NSLog(@"AppDelegate/count/dsItems=%d", [dsItems count]);

}
```

When I run the code,  my RSS parser works properly and I can loop on 10 items in **self.rssParser.rssItems**. I need to access these items in another view to show them in a table, hence I prepare the data in **NSMutableArray * newsRssArray** that I have declared in my .h file

However if I try to add those 10 objects in the NSMutableArray * newsRssArray, I have nothing in the end (see the code output in the debugger). I test my code successfully if I use **NSMutableArray *dsItems** declared inside my function.

Here is gdb output:

```
Attaching to process 47209.
2011-01-29 14:55:24.813 TestApp[47209:207] AppDelegate/count/rssItems=10
2011-01-29 14:55:24.814 TestApp[47209:207] AppDelegate/count/newsRssArray=0
2011-01-29 14:55:24.815 TestApp[47209:207] AppDelegate/count/dsItems=10
(gdb)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @robin That’s the correct syntax for synthesizing a property whose name is different from the corresponding backing instance variable.

Comment: @ceyquem Why do you declare `NSMutableArray *rssItem` in your enumeration and repeatedly cast it to `NewsRss *` inside the loop? You should declare `NewsRss *rssItem` in your enumeration instead.

Comment: @ceyquem Paste the code where you initialise `newsRssArray`. If its `count` returns zero then the most probable cause is that you haven’t actually allocated/inited the array.

Comment: @bavarious: good point for the cast in the loop, that was an unchanged old version of the loop to be optimized, thanks

Comment: @bavarious: i am confused, newRssArray is a property of the AppDelegate, I thought it was not necessary to allocate it. Where (in which function) and how should I initialize it?

Comment: @bavarious: OMG I see my mistake now, you are right! Let me test this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just glancing over the code you have supplied, I don't see where you initialize newsRssArray. Is this in another place or did you forget to init?

Comment: I agree.  use an NSLog to see if _newsRssArray is nil in your log statements.

Comment: There were 2 problems in my code: I did not declare _newsRssArray properly in the .h (missing _) and I replaced _newsRssArray by self.newsRssArray in the .m code that does not work. Both self.newsRssArray and _newsRssArray dont work.

Comment: Ah, yes. Have to be careful with small details like that :)

Comment: you likely do not need to declare _newRssArray in the .h - the newer compiler will handle that for you, the property/synthesize is good enough; you absolutely should alloc/init the value at some point of initialization … [`nil` count] == 0

Answer (score 0):

Just may be you are adding the items to `_newsRssArray` instead of `newsRssArray`

Comment: There were 2 problems in my code: I did not declare _newsRssArray properly in the .h (missing _) and I replaced _newsRssArray by self.newsRssArray in the .m code that does not work. Both self.newsRssArray and _newsRssArray dont work.